How to Debug PCBs - Ardino Nano and Shift Registers
Over the last couple of months I've build a small system based on an Ardino Nano. Because it has a limited number of pins I've used a few 74HC595 Shift Registers chained together to increase the number of outputs I can effectively drive. I built the prototype on breadboard and when it worked I had a PCB made up. As this is a first attempt at a PCB I've added test points for all my signals and power connections.
I've solder up my boards and, thankfully, have socked all of my chip. When I slowly started adding chips to the sockets I discovered that when I add a specific 74HC595 (the second in the chain) the power LED on the Nano becomes dim. When I measure the power across the test points it's dropped from 5v to 2.6v, I can't understand why. So far I've tried:

Checking all the pins on the offending 74HC595 for shorts
Checking for power (Vcc and Gnd) to all the 74HC595 chips
Checking that none of the pins (except VCC, GND and ~SRCLR) are connected to a power rail
Checking that the SRCLK and RCLK are connected to the correct pins of the Nano - the ones shared with the other 74HC595.
Checking the SER pin is connected to QH' of the upstream 74HC595.
Swapping the 74HC595 out for another chip
Removing the chips that will be driven by the offending 74HC595, so the output lines are floating.
Removing the decoupling capacitor
Commenting out the code on the Nano that drives the 74HC595 chain.

The chip that should be driving ~OE has also been removed, so this will be floating, but I don't think this should be a problem and the downstream chip has also been removed.
I'm not sure what else to check. Any ideas?
For reference I've added a circuit diagram, The rogue chip is U2


Can you show the PCB layout and populated board as well as the schematic? The issue might be with the PCB layout and/or any error in how the components were populated.

What are D0-D7? Do you realize that the tool will connect the D0 at U1 to the D0 at U2 possibly causing contention on the Q outputs? Probe the Q outputs with both ICs installed, any signal not near zero or 5V is a sign of contention.

@Mattman944 D0 -> D7 are a bus that should be shared. The idea is that the Nano can latch in some data and the upstream chips can assert either ~P0 or ~P1 to select which 595 to read (although at the moment the upstream system isn't populated). This worked on the prototype, so I've been assuming that part of design is OK

Don't let /OE float, it is a random generator.

jens, Mattman944, putting your comments together I see what is happening. Because ~P0 and ~P1 are floating we Iget into a situation where both driving D0 -> D7 at the same time (If I had populate the upstream circuit this could not happen). The data in the two 74HC595's are random at this point, so statistically at least one of these pins will be driven high by one 74HC595 while the other drives it low. The short I was looking for is through the chips! I can prove my PCB is fine by removing U1 and inserting U2 - there is no short. Could one of you submit an answer to this effect for credits?

Both 74HC595 share a common parallel bus at the 8 outputs. If the output enable pins (/OE) are left floating, they may read as low or high, depending on PCB leakage currents and E fields around them.
At power up the shift registers have a pseudo random content, often the same per chip, but different between chips.
Here I expect both output enable read as low (= active), which creates a bus collision with multiple outputs driving the bus lines with different logic levels.
The supply current will increase, probably up to 35 mA per bit (see: Continuous output current / page 4 of the datasheet).
